# Blank chart display when load Highchart data using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, json, highcharts, struts

I'm having problem with highchart.

I'm trying to populate data from struts action by using ajax.

Here is my code

Jquery

```
$.getJSON("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/c/MonthlyGraphAjax?method=monthlyGraph&selectionList=${selectionList}&reportDateMonth=${reportDateMonth}", function(data){
    /*manual insert*/
    dchart.xAxis.categories.push(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30)
    dchart.series.push({name:'John',data:[99,155,148,136,121,0,0,153,173,161,128,128,0,0,45,109,164,150,98,0,0,165,114,151,108,0,0,0,0,0]},{name:'Doe',data:[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
    /*end manual insert*/

    /*capture to input field*/
    $('#categories').val(data.Graph.Categories)
    $('#series').val(data.Graph.Series)

    /*JSON from struts*/
    //dchart.xAxis.categories.push(data.Graph.Categories)
    //dchart.series.push(data.Graph.Series)
    $('#graphContainer').highcharts(dchart);

})
```

Response from action class

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("{\"Graph\":");
            out.print("{");
                out.print("\"Series\":\""+series+"\",\"Categories\":\""+categories+"\"");
            out.print("}");
        out.print("}");

        response.setContentType("application/json");
```

JSON structure retrieve from action class as below (from firebug console)

```
{"Graph":
    {
        "Series":
            "{name:'John',data:[99,155,148,136,121,0,0,153,173,161,128,128,0,0,45,109,164,150,98,0,0,165,114,151,108,0,0,0,0,0]},
            {name:'Doe',data:[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}"
            ,
        "Categories":"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30"
    }
}
```

The problem is when I manually insert the JSON it's working fine, but json from action class display blank chart. I also capture the json from action class in the input field, the value are exactly the same like I manually hard coded.

Can somebody help me, what am I miss in my code.

Comment: The problem is with your action class, where `series` and `categories` aren't JSON part, but only string.

Comment: Thanx @PawełFus for your advice. yeah the problem with my action class. The JSON is not valid. Right now my chart working fine with little modification in my action class and also javascript.